# Mongoose find() issues with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongoose

I cannot find a way to get my find function to work.
I would like to find all billIds from the bills collection and then check for each billId inside the transaction DB.

The problem is, because of the aSynch - I reckon, the id doesn't update on my loop.
Here is the code:

```
Bills.find({type: bill_type, endDate: {"$gte" : new Date(year + "-" + month + "-1")}}).find(function(err, bills){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        details.bills = bills;

        for(key in bills){
            var billId = bills[key]._id;
            console.log("BillId: " + billId); // Here the ids are unique (which is what I want)

             Transactions.find({billId : billId}, function(err, transactions){
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error: '+ err)
                } else {
                    console.log("Transaction BillId: " + billId); // Here I get always the same ID - which is not quiet what I need.
                }
            });


            //console.log(transactions);
        }

       res.send(details);  
    });
```

There result at the console is:

```
BillId: 549bf0597886c3763e000001
BillId: 54a014bfac01ca3526000001
BillId: 54a015753547a6c026000001
```

^ Good result - Comes from the first console.log inside the for().

and then:

```
Transaction BillId: 54a015753547a6c026000001
Transaction BillId: 54a015753547a6c026000001
Transaction BillId: 54a015753547a6c026000001
```

^ Bad result - Its repeating the last result from the for() and I need all results.

At the first console.log(), when I get the results from the first find() (`Bills.find()`), I can see all the ids on the log but when I try to get them inside the second Find (`Transactions.find()`), they repeat the last id.
So in this current state I am not able to query the db for each id. Any help on this is appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var billId = bills[item]._id;` should be `var billId = item._id`.

Comment: Thats not the point. I'm getting the billId there, the problem is that when I try to execute a `Transactions.Find()` on each billId, the billId is always the last billId from the `Bills.find()`. Also, your suggestion will not work since the item represent the key in my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic mistake of closure function inside the loop.

Your variable value change every loop step. Your function on the other hand will be executed later ( after some time ) when the variable already changed many times.

Take a look on the links for clarification:

[Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

[Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Answer (score 0):

If your `Transactions.find` function is asynchronous, its callback runs at a later point in time, long after the `for ... in` cycle is finished. At that time, `billId` has the value it was assigned on the last run of the `for ... in` cycle. Therefore, all runs of the callback print out that value.

If you want to hold on to the value, you'll have to create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) somewhere, like this:

```
(function (id) {
    Transactions.find(..., function (...) {
        // ... use `id` here
    });
})(billId);
```

---

If `bills` is an `Array` or if you're using some utility library like [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach), you could use iteration function like `Array.prototype.map` or `lodash.each` that uses a closure, so that you wouldn't have to create one separately.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect!

Thanks for the tips guys. I resolved it using [Underscore each function](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Here is how: 
Instead of looping with `for`, I simple replaced the for by `_.each` as in the below example:

```
Bills.find({type: bill_type, endDate: {"$gte" : new Date(year + "-" + month + "-1")}}).find(function(err, bills){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    details.bills = bills;

    _.each(bills, function(item){        
        var billId = item._id; 
        console.log("BillId: " + billId); 

         Transactions.find({billId : billId}, function(err, transactions){
            if (err) {
                console.log('error: '+ err)
            } else {
                console.log("Transaction BillId: " + billId);
            }
        });


        //console.log(transactions);
    });

   res.send(details);  
});
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, it's better to mark it as _accepted_ than to repost the whole code with a tiny change in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks! But I actually like to post exactly what solve the problem as I believe not everyone here are experts like you guys and a suggestion doesn't always clarify what exactly you need to do to get your problem solved. So posting the right-to-the-dot solution will help other amateurs like me.